# How to retrieve RSS feed?

Tags: android, rss

I would like to retrieve the title and description from the link `app2.nea.gov.sg/data/rss/nea_psi.xml`. It's an RSS feed. How can I do this?

my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /** Create a new layout to display the view */
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(1);

        /** Create a new textview array to display the results */
        TextView name[];
        TextView website[];


        try {

            URL url = new URL(
                    "http://app2.nea.gov.sg/data/rss/nea_psi.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

            /** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
            name = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
            website = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];


            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                name[i] = new TextView(this);
                website[i] = new TextView(this);


                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = ((Document) fstElmnt).getElementsByTagName("title");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = ((Node) nameElement).getChildNodes();
                name[i].setText("title = "
                        + ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                NodeList websiteList = ((Document) fstElmnt).getElementsByTagName("description");
                Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
                websiteList = ((Node) websiteElement).getChildNodes();
                website[i].setText("description  = "
                        + ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());



                layout.addView(name[i]);
                layout.addView(website[i]);


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

        /** Set the layout view to display */
        setContentView(layout);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name ="@+id/result"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class XMLParsingDOMExample extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> title;
    ArrayList<String> description;

    public TextView title_text;
    public TextView des_text;

    //ItemAdapter adapter1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainpage_listitem_activity);

        //ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        title = new ArrayList<String>();
        description = new ArrayList<String>();  

        title_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        des_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.des_text);

        try {

            URL url = new URL(
                    "http://app2.nea.gov.sg/data/rss/nea_psi.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);       

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("title");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();         

                title.add(""+ ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("description");
                Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
                websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();

                description.add(""+ ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());           

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }


        title_text.setText(""+title.get(0));

        String temp = Html.fromHtml(description.get(0)).toString(); 
        String a[] = temp.split("\\)");
        des_text.setText(""+a[0]+")");
    }
```

mainpage_listitem_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     > 
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/title_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
                android:text="title"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>   

             <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/des_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="description "
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i pasted full source code here see link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848510/retrieve-rss-feed-and-display-it-in-text-view/17850241#17850241

Comment: take a look at my code that I've pasted. Is it what  you mean?

Comment: i edited your code see..!

Comment: I saw  it.. Thanks,

IF I would like to grab hold on just 1 data 
for example "PSI TIME 2pm"
Is it able to be done?

Comment: String temp = title.get(position); then String a[] = temp.split("at"); in a[1] you can get date and time  and String b[] = temp.split("and"); in b[0] you can get PSI.

Comment: I'm sorry,
but I not sure where do I add.
pardon me, 
I'm new to android

Comment: Hmm From title what are the data's you want... and what you want to display..

Comment: Hi,
I would like to display
PSI and PM2.5 Readings as at 24 Jul 2013 1pmPSI and PM2.5 Readings as at 24 Jul 2013 1pm
PSI : 18-38 (Good)

Comment: actully I want to get this
 <item>
            <title>PSI and PM2.5 Readings as at 25 Jul 2013 3pm</title>
            <description><![CDATA[PSI and PM2.5 Readings as at 25 Jul 2013 3pm<br />PSI : 22-36 (Good)<br />12-18 μg/m<sup>3</sup>]]></description>
            <link>http://www.nea.gov.sg</link>
            <pubDate>25 Jul 2013 3pm</pubDate>
            <psi>PSI : 22-36 (Good)</psi>
            <pm25><![CDATA[12-18 μg/m<sup>3</sup>]]></pm25>
        </item>

However in text view form not list view

Comment: from the same link
"http://app2.nea.gov.sg/data/rss/nea_psi.xml"

Comment: hmm k you don't want edit in title. you want edit in description correct.. then before this line holder.des_text.setText(""+Html.fromHtml(description.get(position)).toString()); add String temp = Html.fromHtml(description.get(position)); String a[] = temp.split("\\)"); then holder.des_text.setText(""+a[0]+")")

Comment: I want to be display as textview in the activity_main

Comment: in that url you have 10 items. If you want to display as textview means you need atleast 20 textviews in activity_main...

Comment: no-p
I only want to retrieve mainly just 1 item.

Comment: Meaning in all the RSS feed that I've in the URL,
I only wish to retrieve the first item

Comment: do you know how to do this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852206/merging-2-rss-feed-together?noredirect=1#comment26062510_17852206

Answer (score 0):

Use the following library to fetch RSS feeds:

https://github.com/ahorn/android-rss

Comment: there isn't any project inside that I could follow after

Comment: The link? Yes it's a rss library project which you can use to fetch rss feed from xml links. Download as zip and follow the instructions given there. I myself used it in one project.

Comment: I couldn't.
I shall try it again